# azure java iot hub mqtt doesnt connect

Tags: java, azure, mqtt, iot, raspberry-pi3

the java samples in the sdk work fine in a machine with windows 10, but when i try to make it work in a raspberry pi 3 model B it doesnt connect, no matter what protocol i use, can someone help me, i provide all data neccesary.

The next images show the information I got when I try to run it. It seems like the client doesnt open.
If it helps, the same raspberry pi 3 model B is sending data to the azure iot hub to be used in the stream analytics and then shown in power bi. That data is been sending in to a different hub, but i dont know if that is causing trouble with the hub im trying to use. That data ys using languague phyton.

Im using this tutorial, azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/doc/get_started/java-run-sample.md and, again, in a machine with windows 10 works fine.

[image: amqps]

[image: mqtt]

Comment: Please post code rather than images when possible.

Comment: It's insecure to post your iot hub connection string with sharedaccesskey.

Comment: Yes,it was a stupid mistake from my part, I´ll try to be more careful, thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This is a good catch!

After some investigation, I've been able to narrow it down to the OpenJDK problem, not sure what the root cause is though.

However, you should be able to connect to Azure IoT Hub if you follow the below steps,

1. Uninstall OpenJDK, using `sudo apt remove --purge "^openjdk.*"`
2. Download [JDK 1.8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), you should choose ***Linux ARM 32 Hard Float ABI*** version
3. Extract it somewhere, using `tar xzvf xxx.tar.gz`
4. Add the new JAVA_HOME enviornment variable to your JDK folder, and include $JAVA_HOME/bin to your $PATH.
5. Run the java sample.

So now my mqtt sample output looks like below,
[image]

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, i will try that!

Comment: A little update, i was able to make it work with the jdk-8-oracle-arm32, but only on amqps and https, still having troubles with mqtt, but for now I can work amqps.

Comment: @FabianVelazquezZuñiga, I've updated my answer with mqtt sample output, so you can see mqtt is working with me.

Comment: cool, i will try the Linux ARM 32 Hard Float ABI version to see if i can make the mqtt protocol work, thanks!

Comment: @FabianVelazquezZuñiga, any luck with mqtt?

Comment: hi @Jackie, not yet, im still getting the same error with mqtt, but i think its somekind of trouble with my raspberry an the fact that im using it to send data to one hub at the same time, still looking for a solution, if i get it, i´ll post it, meanwhile i´ll use amqps.

Comment: FYI, with the jdk-8-oracle-arm32, someone told me in the sdk  azure issues section, is possible to use the mqtt protocol, also give me an screenshot of him doing it, if anyone want to try it, again, maybe is just my enviroment that doesnt work.

Comment: Hi my final comment here, a guy working for microsoft support team told me this: "It seems that the product group are going to recommend using Oracle and consider that their supported JVM. Thank you for notifying us of this issue"

You can check the thread here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/issues/919#issuecomment-264557394